# How to convert CommonJS require into ES6+ import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a line of code in my Node.js `server.js` file that goes like this:

```
const serverApp = require('../dist/server/app.js').default;
```

I need to convert it into ES6+ style, something like this:

```
import serverApp from '../dist/server/app.js';
// or
import * as serverApp from '../dist/server/app.js';
```

If I do that then I keep getting an error saying `TypeError: (0 , _app.default) is not a function`

I ran a `webpack` production build using `babel` and it does this on the CJS code:

```
const serverApp = require('../dist/server/app.js').default
// ... becomes ...
var serverApp = __webpack_require__(530).default;
```

How can I use ES6+ style to acheive the same thing?

Comment: How does app.js looks like?

Comment: app.js is too big to paste into stackoverflow. It is built with webpack and ends with `module.exports = __webpack_exports__;`

Comment: It seems you are trying to import bundled code. I don't think it's possible, because babel outputs modules not in ES Module type. So you can't import module that is not exports something in ES modules style. You can read more about javascript module types [here](https://medium.com/computed-comparisons/commonjs-vs-amd-vs-requirejs-vs-es6-modules-2e814b114a0b)